# My Textures Disappear in Game Mode

Tags: texturing, uv, game-engine

A bunch of my textures just straight up disappear/turn into solid colours when I hit P to go into game mode on Blender (beds/walls). Im confused because some of them work fine (floor) and i did the exact same thing for all, and cant find any differences in any of the properties for why this would be. They all show up normally in default/edit modes, but as soon as I start the game they are gone. I looked up similar peoples problems to this but couldnt find anything, also idk anything about uv mapping and didnt apply it.
enter image description here

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1cOP8LoLIfezu4raAme4Eag1uDDN-PMta/view?usp=sharing
[image]

[image]

Comment: I don't know what's happening in this case, I messed up with your file and you shouldn't have problems if you: go to Properties Editor > Render tab > Shading panel > Set texture mode from Multitexture to GLSL; Add an hemi lamp to the scene, so you could see the objects; learn how to UV map and remake the textures on your objects, as using GLSL, UV mapping is obligatory. This way you get a much better renderer, have better control over materials and have the 'what you see is what you get' behavior on the 3D Viewport, instead of the unpredictable behavior of Multitexture mode.

Comment: @JoelGomesdaSilva Thank you for your comment! What exactly to I have to do in the GLSL tab? All of the options are currently selected (lights, shaders, shadows, etc.) I will try adding UV mapping in the meantime and reloading the textures. thanks

Comment: Keep the options as they are and everything should be fine, they are only for optimization.